# Как сделать красивый Neon эффект?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qss

Я хочу сделать красивый  и сочный неон эффект 
С возможностью контролировать мощность света
Для этого я построил такой код

```
import sys
import os 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QPoint,Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(800, 800)

        self.setStyleSheet('background:black;')
        # my font
        url = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "icomoon.ttf")
        font_id = QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(url)
        if font_id == -1:
            print('not font')
        font = QtGui.QFont("icomoon",18)            

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        color_1 = '162, 162, 162,'
        color_2 = '255, 255, 255,'
        color_3 = '0, 255, 255,'

        d_ = 1

        power = int(255/100*d_)

        for x in range(6):
            label = QLabel(self)


            color_L = color_1
            glass_L = 255
            size_L = 60
            blut_L = 0


            label.raise_()

            if x < 1 :
                color_L = color_1
            elif x < 2 :
                color_L = color_3
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 3 :
                color_L = color_2
                blut_L = 6
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 4:
                color_L = color_2
                blut_L = 40
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 5 :
                label.lower()
                color_L = color_3
                blut_L = 40
                size_L = 70
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 6 :
                label.lower()
                color_L = color_3
                blut_L = 150
                size_L = 70
                glass_L = power

            label.setText('test')
            label.setStyleSheet('background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);color:rgba({} {}); font-size:{}px;'.format(color_L, glass_L,size_L))
            label.resize(self.width(), self.height())
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

            self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=blut_L)
            label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)






if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

но код слишком грамоздкий.
А свет получился слишком ненатуралистичным
особенно плохо он выглядит если указать слабую интенсивность света.

Есть ли лучшие варианты сделать neon эффект?

или почему он выглядит так плохо?

То что я хочу получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то что я получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую иконки сделаные в программе [icon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)

Answer (score 1):

Уф, добавили бы скриншот насколько плохо. Суть в неоне это цветовой контраст между фоном и самим элементом, либо текстом. Выбираете темный фон и цвет для текста. 
[Вот сайт для подборки контраста цвета фона и текста](https://colorable.jxnblk.com/)

И добавляете тени, желательно, достаточно размытые с таким же цветом, как текст.
Скину вот тут видео, как можно сделать neon на css and html
[вот видео с неоновым серч баром](https://youtu.be/kLrwIJ1HYBk?t=8)
Там на канале еще есть примеры. Спасибо за внимание

Comment: я добавил изображения